# Не подключаются темы Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Не могу подключить темы стилей для компонентов Primefaces, хотя все сделано по спецификации разработчика но почемуто компоненты плывут.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из написаного на в инструкциях на сколько я понял нужно всего подключить зависимости:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>6.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces.themes/all-themes -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
  <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Подключить репозиторий для тем:

```
<repository>
  <id>prime-repo</id>
  <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
  <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

В web.xml прописать оформление темы:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

И при написании разметки добавить обьявление:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Но почемуто при выполнении этих шагов получается то что на снимке. Возможно вы подскажите что ище необходимо добавить для правильной разметки компонентов.

Comment: Тег `h:head` присутствует в разметке страницы?

Comment: да, но проблема не в нем. На сколько я понимаю css темы должен подхватыватся сам и в случае чего спокойно менятся через бин.  Но я могу его подхватить только если пропишу напрямую тег на css. Веселее всего что  нету ошибок.